# About OpenCV coordinates

Tags: c, opencv, coordinates

I had a quick question about OpenCV and how it presents coordinates of a ROI when performing face tracking. I was able to print out (x,y) coordinates. But I'm trying to figure out a good way to plot these coordinates. Does anyone know what are the units? Are they in pixels? Can I plot them in terms of frames or something like that? 
Thanks, I'm still kind of a newbie with OpenCV libraries.

Comment: could not understand your question

Answer (score 7):

OpenCV represents the coordinates in pixels. Top-left corner is defined as **(0,0)**. Direction to the right is **x** (columns), direction to bottom is **y** (rows).

Typically you draw points using `circle(img,center,radius,...)` and lines using `line(img,point1,point2,...)`.